# Using Whylogs 1.1.43 with python 3.8, scala 2.11.8 an spark 2.3.0

Tags: python, scala, pyspark

I' ve been trying to make whylogs v1.1.43 with a spark cluster on python 3.8, spark 2.3.0 and scala 2.11.8.

Using python and pyspark 2.3.0, i can load the spark dataframe but each time i want to make i profile, i get the following error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8uWU.png)

And then using scala, i can also load the dataframe but i can't profile
I use a jar from this link as an option in the spark session : https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ai/whylabs/whylogs-spark_2.11/0.1.1/whylogs-spark_2.11-0.1.1.jar

[Scala session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH0Bi.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcbvP.png)

Does anyone have any idea how to make it work ?

Have tried this tutorial https://docs.whylabs.ai/docs/spark-integration/#scala-example but got a "/tmp/jna-*.jar" :failed to map segment from shared object: operation not permitted" error on building with gradlew

Comment: Please don't use images to share code or error logs

Comment: oh sorry, it was a screenshot and i forgot to copy paste the stacktrace